# What is the purpose of an empty loop in this volatile var example?

Tags: scala, concurrency

Code:

```
  class Page(val txt: String, var position: Int)

  val rand = new Random()
  object Volatile {
    val pages = for(i <- 1 to 5) yield new Page("Na" * rand.nextInt(1000) + " Batman!", -1)
    @volatile var found = false
    for (p <- pages) yield thread {
      var i = 0
      while (i < p.txt.length && !found) if (p.txt(i) == '!') {
        p.position = i
        found = true
      } else i += 1
      while(!found) {}
      log(s"results: ${pages.map(_.position)}")
    }
  }
```

What is the purpose of the empty loop `while(!found) {}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop: `while (i < p.txt.length && !found)` has two conditions for stopping: when the search space is exhausted, or when a match was found. Note that the `found` variable is used in multiple threads: `thread {...}` presumably spawns a new thread.

So there are several possibilities how the threads' loops can play out:

- the thread finds a `'!'` and sets `found`. The first loop breaks, the second doesn't execute.
- another thread sets `found`. The first loop breaks, the second doesn't execute.
- all characters were searched. The first loop breaks, the second executes until another thread finds a `'!'`.

The third one is probably the one you forgot. The consequence is that results are only logged once all loops are finished.

---

Granted, I can't tell you why that code looks like it does: each thread, separately prints the results for all pages, i.e. if there are `n` pages, `n^2` results are logged. Also, all threads access a shared object without synchronization. If the goal was to find exactly one exclamation mark, the code fails. Anyway, these seem like separate issues.

Comment: Well the code does find exactly one exclamation mark (the earliest).

Comment: Presuming there is at least one to be found.

Comment: @qed "Presuming there is at least one to be found." that's another issue I didn't address. But: no, it doesn't find exactly one exclamation mark. If two threads find an exclamation mark at the same time, both will set `p.position`, where `p` is different for each thread. So, both positions will be printed. You can test this by putting a sleep before ` found = true`, and using multiple strings that start with a `!`

Comment: @qed the simplest way would be, once you find `!`, to do checking & updating `found` and updating `position` in a synchronized block (I think it's a method in Scala): `if(p.txt(i) == '!') someObj.synchronized { if(found) { ... } }` But considering the other issues, I would rethink the problem: Do you want to print the results that often? Do you really want to process the results in the worker threads? Do you want the results per-page, though you want to find only one? My conclusions would be to use cancel-able workers and a Future or Queue for getting results to the main thread

Comment: I have posted an answer following your suggestions. Pleas have a look. The goal here is find the exclamation point as early as possible and stop other threads from search once its found. The logging part is merely for demonstration.

Comment: Also, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838751/synchronize-on-a-var-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

If looks like a busy wait. It will continue to check the status of `found`, and execution won't continue until `found` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Silly Freak's suggestions, I have modified the code to use `synchronized` instead of `volatile`:

```
  object AntiVolatile {
    val pages = for (i <- 1 to 15) yield new Page("!Na" * rand.nextInt(1000) + " Batman!", -1)
    var found = Some(false)

    def run(): Unit = {
      for (p <- pages) yield thread {
        var i = 0
        var foundInThread = found.get
        while (i < p.txt.length && !foundInThread)
          if (p.txt(i) == '!') {
            found.synchronized {
              found match {
                case Some(true) => foundInThread = true
                case Some(false) => {
                  p.position = i
                  found = Some(true)
                  Thread.sleep(1)
                }
                case _ =>
              }
            }
          } else i += 1
        // if still not found, wait for another thread to find it.
        def wait(): Unit = {
          found match {
            case Some(false) => wait()
            case _ =>
          }
        }
        wait()
        log(s"results: ${pages.map(_.position)}")
      }
    }
  }
```

No more data race:

```
Thread-29: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-27: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-28: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-26: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-30: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-31: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-32: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-25: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-33: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-34: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-39: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-38: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-37: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-36: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-35: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
```