# Synchronize on a var in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency

The problem is to search among a few pages of text for an exclamation point concurrently and as soon as any of the threads finds it, all the other threads should stop searching.

Code:

```
  object AntiVolatile {
    val pages = for (i <- 1 to 15) yield new Page("!Na" * rand.nextInt(1000) + " Batman!", -1)
    var found = Some(false)

    def run(): Unit = {
      for (p <- pages) yield thread {
        var i = 0
        var foundInThread = found.get
        while (i < p.txt.length && !foundInThread)
          if (p.txt(i) == '!') {
            found.synchronized {
              found match {
                case Some(true) => foundInThread = true
                case Some(false) => {
                  p.position = i
                  found = Some(true)
                  Thread.sleep(1)
                }
                case _ =>
              }
            }
          } else i += 1
        // if still not found, wait for another thread to find it.
        def wait(): Unit = {
          found match {
            case Some(false) => wait()
            case _ =>
          }
        }
        wait()
        log(s"results: ${pages.map(_.position)}")
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems to work ok:

```
Thread-29: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-27: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-28: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-26: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-30: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-31: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-32: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-25: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-33: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-34: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-39: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-38: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-37: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-36: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
Thread-35: results: Vector(0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
```

But then I realized that `found` is not a constant instance because it's reassign to a new `Option` object later. (Why does the code actually work?)

So I came up with a fix:

```
  object AntiVolatile {
    case class Found(var isFound: Boolean)
    val pages = for (i <- 1 to 15) yield new Page("!Na" * rand.nextInt(1000) + " Batman!", -1)
    val found = Found(false)

    def run(): Unit = {
      for (p <- pages) yield thread {
        var i = 0
        var foundInThread = found.isFound
        while (i < p.txt.length && !foundInThread)
          if (p.txt(i) == '!') {
            found.synchronized {
              found match {
                case Found(true) => foundInThread = true
                case Found(false) => {
                  p.position = i
                  found.isFound = true
                  Thread.sleep(1)
                }
                case _ =>
              }
            }
          } else i += 1
        // if still not found, wait for another thread to find it.
        def wait(): Unit = {
          found match {
            case Found(false) => wait()
            case _ =>
          }
        }
        wait()
        log(s"results: ${pages.map(_.position)}")
      }
    }
  }
```

These two versions seem to behave the same, why? I would expect some bug cropping up in the first version.

Link to github repo: https://github.com/kindlychung/learnConcurrentScala/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/learningconcurrency/ch2/Ch2.scala

Comment: That does not seem to be working "ok" to me in either version, as the result sets should not be all the same size and the ! is always at the first position? Maybe I don't get the internal structure of `Page`

Comment: Also, I don't see why you expect them to behave differently at all. All threads create a value for `foundInThread` and iterate over it (not `found`), until they finish their respective page. Synchronization is only at the end (thus kind of irrelevant) and you don't seem to be saving yourself any work. Plus, you are doing busy wait on all threads, which is terrible :-(

Comment: The busy waiting is purely for demonstration purposes. Please see the github link I added.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear if you are interested in learning concurrency or if you are solving an actual problem. With that being said, I am going to assume that you are attempting to solve the problem.

Why not use Futures?

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Await, Future}
import scala.util.Random
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {

  case class Page(number: Int, text: String)

  val pages = for (i <- 1 to 15) yield Page(i, "!Na" * Random.nextInt(1000) + " Batman! ")

  val searchFutures = pages.map { p => Future {
    val position = p.text.indexOf("!")
    s"Exclamation mark found on page ${p.number} at position: $position"
  }}

  val firstCompleted = Future.firstCompletedOf(searchFutures)

  val result = Await.result(firstCompleted, Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  println(result)

}
```